# How can there be two separate Android System under "Running services"?

Tags: system, 8.0-oreo, verizon, processes, lg-v20

My Verizon LG V20 (Android 8.0) appears to be running two Android Systems at the same time, but, I'm pretty sure that isn't possible.

Am I wrong on this or am I seeing things?  Also, the timing between the two appears off by about 4 seconds. Just seems pretty odd to me.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: what is inside those processes? are they also the same or what?

Comment: It also instantly sent a bug report as soon as i took those screen shots.

Comment: android system app running means some background services run by any system app. Example: blue tooth, wifi etc. Here on screen shot, you can see that first one uses, telephone and  second used for system log purposes. Try to remove phone app from memory(RAM)/running services and check after that. The process  "Android System" running will get destroyed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there is only one Android System running in your device. The other one is deceptively named by Verizon.

If you check the process name, it starts with com.vzw.*. That package name convention can also be found in [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vzw.hss.myverizon) from Verizon.

I'm speculating this based on the process name that it gathers data (can't say what and why) and sends it to Verizon.

If you're concerned about that process or the corresponding package, you can disable it using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb).

```
adb shell pm disable-user com.vzw.qualitydatalog
```

**Note** that this may destabilize your system with factory reset left as the only fix, so proceed at your own risk and with backups already taken and stored outside the phone.

Comment: Would down voters care to explain why?

Comment: @beeshyams I was about to comment the same. I'm thinking my speculation might be the reason, but I clearly mentioned "speculating" instead of mixing it in my answer.